# jQuery basic appending

Tags: jquery, append

I used jQuerys' `$("...").append()` and found out, that it is more advanced than I thought it is. For instance, the following sample

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("body").append("<div>");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

outputs

```
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

. As you can see, jQuery added the closing tag itself. In my case, I want to append just the opening tag, because I want to fill this element peu à peu.
For example

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("body").append("<div>");
    if(...){
        $("body").append("true");
    }else{
        $("body").append("false");
    }        
});
```

outputs

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    true
</body>
```

instead of

```
<body>
    <div>true
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about appending to the div after it has been appended to the body?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("body").append("<div>");
    if(...){
        $("body div").append("true");
    }else{
        $("body div").append("false");
    }        
});
```

Comment: this is possible, and I think I am going to tackle it like this, but it doesn't seem to be quite intuitive for me. I need to keep tracked of every sub-dom-element I add

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append just an opening tag because that doesn't translate to an actual DOM element.  That's only a piece of a DOM element which isn't something that can be turned into a DOM element.

If what you're trying to create is this:

```
<body>
    <div>true
</body>
```

That isn't valid HTML.  It would have to be this to be valid:

```
<body>
    <div>true</div>
</body>
```

You could solve your problem like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var myDiv = $("<div>");    // create DOM element
    if(...){
        myDiv.html("true");    // set contents of DOM element
    }else{
        myDiv.html("false");
    }        
    $(document.body).append(myDiv);   // append DOM element to the page
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eSncS/